# Canvas doesn't work on background pages - Collaborative drawing application with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, socket.io

I have a problem with an application that would allow people to draw lines on the same canvas. Currently, my application only work locally. When I have multiple pages opened, the application works fine, the same drawing is on every canvas. However, when a page is reduced or opened in another tab, this page doesn't have the same canvas, most of the lines that should appear on this canvas are missing.
To reproduce the content of a canvas every time we add a line, I use the canvas method DrawImage().

Here is the code of the client side:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:4000';
var socket = io.connect(url);
var mouseData= {};
var startLine= false;
var first= {};
var last= {};
var tmpPosition= {};
var canvas = document.getElementById('tableauBlanc');
var contextCanvas1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
var Images = new Image();
var data;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(MouseEvent) {
    tmpPosition=.x = MouseEvent.clientX;
    tmpPosition=.y = MouseEvent.clientY;
    tmpPosition== adaptMousePosition(tmpPosition=.x, tmpPosition=.y);
    if (startLine) {
        socket.emit('deleteAndRedrawCanvas', Images);
        mouseData.px = first.x;
        mouseData.py = first.y;
        mouseData.dx = tmpPosition=.x;
        mouseData.dy = tmpPosition=.y;
        mouseData.validate= false;
        socket.emit('DrawLine', mouseData);
    }
}

});

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(MouseEvent) {
    if (startDroite) {
        last.x = MouseEvent.clientX;
        last.y = MouseEvent.clientY;
        last= adaptMousePosition(last.x, last.y);
        contextCanvas1.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
        mouseData.px = first.x;
        mouseData.py = first.y;
        mouseData.dx = last.x;
        mouseData.dy = last.y;
        mouseData.validate= true;
        socket.emit('DrawLine', mouseData);
        startLine= false;
    } else {

        first.x = MouseEvent.clientX;
        first.y = MouseEvent.clientY;
        first= adaptMousePosition(first.x, first.y);
        startLine= true;
    }

});

socket.on('Draw', function(mouseData) {
    contextCanvas1.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    DrawLine(mouseData.px, mouseData.py, mouseData.dx, mouseData.dy);
    if (mouseData.fini == true) {
        setTimeout(DrawCanvas, 20);
    }
});


function DrawCanvas() {
    data = canvas.toDataURL();
    Images.src = data;
    Images.onload = function() {
        Images.src = data;
        contextCanvas1.drawImage(Images, 0, 0, 500, 500);
    }
}

function DrawLine(px, py, dx, dy) {

    contextCanvas1.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    contextCanvas1.moveTo(px, py);
    contextCanvas1.lineTo(dx, dy);
    contextCanvas1.stroke();

}

socket.on('deleteAndRedrawCanvas', function(Images) {
    contextCanvas1.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    contextCanvas1.beginPath();
});

function adaptMousePosition(posX, posY) {
    var gap= canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: posX - gap.left,
        y: posY - gap.top
    };
}
```

Thanks for any pieces of advice.
By the way, that's the first time that I'm using Javascript and NodeJS, my code may be badly structured.

Comment: function and variable names would be highly appreciated in english :)

Comment: I edited it, everything is in english